# Health & Status of EMR Cluster using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-emr

I want to get the health status of EMR Cluster using boto3.
If it is healthy,then I should be able to run my jobs.How to know if the cluster is healthy ?
I ran the below code and it returned a dictionary.

```
import boto3

emr_client = boto3.client('emr')
clusters = emr_client.list_clusters(ClusterStates=['STARTING', 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING'])
for cluster in clusters['Clusters']:  
  cluster_id = cluster['Id']
  response = emr_client.list_instances(ClusterId=cluster_id)
  print(response)
```

Output :

```
{'Instances': [{'Id': 'ci-xxxx', 'Ec2InstanceId': 'i-xxxx', 'PublicDnsName': '', 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-xxxx.ec2.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': 'xxxx', 'Status': {'State': 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'StateChangeReason': {}, 'Timeline': {'CreationDateTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 27, 13, 8, 28, 758000, tzinfo=tzlocal())}}, 'InstanceGroupId': 'ig-xxxx', 'Market': 'ON_DEMAND', 'InstanceType': 'm5.xlarge', 'EbsVolumes': [{'Device': 'xxx', 'VolumeId': 'vol-xxx'}, {'Device': 'xxx', 'VolumeId': 'vol-xxxx'}]}, {'Id': 'ci-xxxx', 'Ec2InstanceId': 'i-xxxx', 'PublicDnsName': '', 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-xxxx.ec2.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': 'xxxx', 'Status': {'State': 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'StateChangeReason': {}, 'Timeline': {'CreationDateTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 27, 13, 8, 28, 758000, tzinfo=tzlocal())}}, 'InstanceGroupId': 'ig-xxxx', 'Market': 'ON_DEMAND', 'InstanceType': 'm5.xlarge', 'EbsVolumes': [{'Device': 'xxx', 'VolumeId': 'vol-xxxx'}, {'Device': 'xxx', 'VolumeId': 'vol-xxxx'}]}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'xxxx', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxx', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '989', 'date': 'Mon, 27 Dec 2021 19:08:55 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

How can we fetch the instances status out of this ? And list_instances is the correct method to look for the health of the EMR Cluster ?

Thanks.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Hi Marcin,
Thanks for your time.
I tried the below code :
```
import boto3
emr_client = boto3.client('emr')
clusters = emr_client.list_clusters(ClusterStates=['STARTING', 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING'])
for cluster in clusters['Clusters']:  
  cluster_id = cluster['Id']
  response = emr_client.list_instances(ClusterId=cluster_id)
  print(response)
```

Output was a dictionary.Could you please help how to fetch the instance id from the above output and use in describe instance status to get the instances' health?
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest making a new with the new code and errors.

Comment: @Marcin I have updated the question here ... Would you be able to help please ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that what you want is health of instances in the cluster. If so you have to [list_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_instances), and there you can find their `Status`. You can also iterate over the instance ids from the previous command and use [describe_instance_status](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status) for more details.

Comment: Yes I fetched the instance ids using list_instances , fed the ids to describe_instance_status and got the instance & system status.Thanks Marcin.

Comment: @Sonu No problem. Glad it worked out :-)